# iTextSharp generating corrupted PDF in WPF

Tags: wpf, pdf, itext

I am new to programming with iTextSharp. i have an application that writes in PDF file. File is written in word and than saved in PDF (there are 2 pages). My problem is, that when I want to write on PDF I see the data that was written on but the output PDF is corrupted. I don't understand why PDF gets corrupted?

```
    Public Sub WriteForm(TemplateFilePath As String, NewFilePath As String, data As FormData)
    'input output files
    Dim oldFile As String = TemplateFilePath
    Dim newFile As String = NewFilePath

    'if file already exists then delete it
    If System.IO.File.Exists(newFile) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(newFile)
    End If

    ' open the reader
    Dim reader As New PdfReader(oldFile)
    Dim size As Rectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)
    Dim document As New Document(size)

    ' open the writer
    Dim fs As New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)
    document.Open()

    'write data to first page
    Me.WriteData(reader, writer, data)

    'write second page
    Me.AppendCopiedPage(document, writer, reader, 2)

    ' close the streams 
    document.Close()
    fs.Close()
    writer.Close()
    reader.Close()

End Sub
```

'code for WriteData

```
    Private Sub WriteData(reader As PdfReader, writer As PdfWriter, data As FormData)`
    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
    Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK)
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10)

    ' create the first page and add it to the pdf
    Dim page1 As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1)
    cb.AddTemplate(page1, 0, 0)
    Me.WriteText(cb, data.SID, 110, 653)
           ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Close fs after the writer.

Comment: unfortunetly it doesn't work:(I think I may have a problem with Me.WriteData --                                                        Private Sub WriteData(reader As PdfReader, writer As PdfWriter, data As FormData)
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
        Dim page1 As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1)
        cb.AddTemplate(page1, 0, 0)
        '...
    End Sub

Comment: Can you update your question with the WriteData code

Comment: added in upper window

Comment: Please also provide a sample PDF illustrating the issue.